# npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...aye-websocket":"0.11.'

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

l  try run firebase init

```
app-functions>firebase init
```

while installing dependencies with npm I get the error below

```
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...aye-websocket":"0.11.'
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\victorkabike\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-07T12_47_43_502Z-debug.log

NPM install failed, continuing with Firebase initialization...
```

Comment: try running `npm cache clean --force` and install firebase globally